# Want to pass application User_ID with Salesforce Oauth URL

Tags: javascript, php, oauth, salesforce, crm

I am building a chrome extension and want to add Oauth of salesforce but having issue with passing my application user_id along with it can anyone suggest me any solutions I have tried it with ajax & parameter passing but doesn't seem like working.(Basically I want to pass app user_id along with Oauth url is there any way i can do this)

Approach 1. window.open(OAuthUrl,"_system","location=yes");
and made a callback.php file with Access token api call curl

Approach 2. Ajax to call url.php which has header(location:url) and callback.php for callback

If you actually have any solutions please get in touch this is a emergency task